# Magento2 does not automatically update changes

Tags: magento2

I am developing a magento module. I did set the mode to developer, clear cache. However, everytime I changed the template files or js files, I cannot see the changes reflecting on my webshop.

I can only see the changes after running this command. I think it is not relevant but only when running this command, I can see the changes

```
 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Do you guys have any idea why that happened?

Comment: Did you try cache:flush command to see your changes ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I cannot see the changes

Comment: May be permission issue ?